# Multieselect Combobox performance issues (ExtJS 7.3)

Tags: extjs, combobox, multi-select, extjs7

I am experiencing some performance issues with my multiselect combobox. The combobox is filled with around 2000 entries and when activated, it takes almost 2 seconds to render/expand.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3bfv&view/editor

Does someone know how to improve the performance or a better usage of this control?

Regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the displayed list cannot be `infinite` which would have make it quickly displayed.

I would suggest to use combobox field with **remote loading** if you have a large number of entries.

Now, if you look at the generated DOM nodes for the picker, there may be some useless things.

For each item, you are getting :

```
<div id="ext-simplelistitem-1" data-componentid="ext-simplelistitem-1" class="x-listitem x-component x-boundlistitem x-layout-auto-item x-first" data-xid="7" data-viewid="ext-boundlist-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="1">
    <div class="x-body-el x-listitem-body-el x-component-body-el" id="ext-element-24">
        <div class="x-tool-dock x-listitem-tool-dock x-component-tool-dock" id="ext-element-28">
            <div class="x-tool-zone x-start" id="ext-element-27">
                <div id="ext-tool-1" data-componentid="ext-tool-1" class="x-tool x-component x-disabled x-passive x-selected-icon x-tool-listitem x-component-listitem x-start" data-xid="8">
                    <div class="x-icon-el x-font-icon x-fa fa-check" id="ext-element-26"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="x-inner-el x-listitem-inner-el x-component-inner-el x-tool-anchor" id="ext-element-25">
                <div class="x-innerhtml" id="ext-element-29"><span class="x-list-label">Alabama</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the `floatedPicker` (and `edgePicker` for small devices) config of the Select field (See also `picker`).

It is possible to make simplier DOM nodes :

```
itemTpl: '{name}', // removes 2000 spans
floatedPicker: {
  itemConfig: {
    xtype: 'component' // removes 12.000 divs
  }
}
```

There are surely more optimizations that could be done to reduce the display time.
For example, the first render lasts some seconds. It may be Models creation, collection/store operations, too many events fired, ...

Answer (score 0):

With that many selections, it bloats your code on the front end.  I would try to hook up an autoselection with the combobox. I did something similar for a zipcode selection box.  Instead of listing out 45K zip codes in the united states, you let the user pare down the selection themselves.

```
          {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                id: 'zipCodeComboId',
                label: 'select zip code',
                queryMode: 'remote',
                displayField: 'zipCode',
                valueField: 'zipCode',
                value: '000',
                height:50,
                forceSelection: true,
                typeAhead: false,
                minChars: 3,
                store: {
                    type: 'zipCodes'
                }
            }
```

and your store could look something like:

```
Ext.define('yourapp.store.ZipCodes', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

alias: 'store.zipCodes',

model: 'yourapp.model.ZipCodes',
storeId: 'zipCodesStoreId',
autoLoad: false,
idProperty: 'zipCode',
fields: [
    'zipCode', 'city', 'state', 'updatedDt'
],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/searchYourZipCodes',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'values'
    }
},
```

});